# How Do I Enable Error Log in Homebrew's PHP Formula?

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to debug a filter function in WordPress and I can't get the PHP formula of Homebrew to enable the error logs. I've tried commenting out this line: `error_log = /Users/samuelbacay/Sites/php_errors.log` in `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` and restarting the server but there's still no log file in my Sites folder. I've also tried `echo` but I guess it doesn't work since what I'm trying to do is filter function hooked to `post_thumbnail_class`.

This is how I'm doing an error log: `error_log( 'Image Path: ' . $image_path);`.

Comment: It was finally logging errors but my error_log()s isn't being included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. I didn't know that the WordPress filter I was trying to use didn't exist. That's why there was no error log. I got the code from ChatGPT and I automatically assumed that it exists. Now, I know to check if it exists first.